# If $G$ is abelian, show the Prüfer rank $r(G)$ is finite iff $\max\{ d(H)\}$ is finite, for $d(H)$ the min number of generators of f.g. $H\le G$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, finitely-generated, infinite-groups

This is part of **Exercise 4.2.2** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3APr%C3%BCfer%20rank%2C%20OR%20content%3Aabelian%20group%2C%20OR%20content%3Afinite&p=10) and [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Babelian-groups%5D+pr%C3%BCfer+rank+finite), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

On page 98 to 99, *ibid.*, we have

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $G$. Then  $S$ is called *linearly independent*, or simply *independent*, if $0\notin S$ and, given distinct elements $s_1,\dots, s_r$ of $S$ and integers $m_1,\dots, m_r$, the relation $m_1s_1+\dots+m_rs_r=0$ implies $m_is_i=0$ for all $i$.

. . . and . . .

> If $p$ is prime and $G$ is an abelian group, the *$p$-rank* of $G$
>
> $$r_p(G)$$
>
> is defined as the cardinality of a maximal independent subset of elements of $p$-power order. Similarly the *$0$-rank* or *torsion-free rank*
>
> $$r_0(G)$$
>
> is the cardinality of a maximal independent subset of elements of infinite order. Also important is the *Prüfer rank*, often just called *the rank of $G$*,
>
> $$r(G)=r_0(G)+\max_{p} r_p(G).$$

*(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3587278/104041) for how the $\sup$ instead of the $\max$ is more appropriate. I don't think it effects the exercise is question though.)*

### The Question:

> If $G$ is an abelian group, show that $r(G)$ is finite if and only if $\max\{ d(H)\}$ is finite where $H$ ranges over the finitely generated subgroups of $G$. [. . .] [*Note:* $d(H)$ is the minimum number of generators of $H$.]

### Thoughts:

I doubt there's an easy way to tackle this using iff-statements, so I proceed as follows . . .

Suppose $G$ is an abelian group such that $r(G)=n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$. Then

$$r_0(G)+\max_{p} r_p(G)=n.$$

This implies $r_0(G)=s$ and $\max_{p}r_p(G)=t$ for some $s,t\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$ such that $n=s+t$.

Where do I go from here?

---

Of course, if $G$ is finite, then $r_0(G)=0$. In fact, upon reflection, the question is trivial for finite $G$. (Right? Because each (finitely-generated) $H\le G$ must be finite . . . )

---

Next, I should look at the sufficiency.

Suppose $G$ is an (infinite) abelian group such that

$$\max\{ d(H)\mid H\le G, H \text{ is finitely-generated}\}$$

is finite, where $d(H)$ is the minimum number of generators of $H$.

Where do I go from here?

---

<strike>I can see, sort of, that $r_0(G)=0$, but I don't know how to justify it and it wouldn't shock me if it's not necessary. I feel the same way about the fact that $r_0(G)$ is finite, except that it must be true in order for $r(G)$ to be finite.</strike>

---

Nowhere have I used that $G$ is abelian.

---

This seems like a problem I ought to be able to answer myself, given enough time. The type of answer I'm hoping for is a full solution but I'd be happy with a good hint or two.

---

Please help :)

Comment: I would prove it for torsionfree abelian groups first; that will strongly require abelianness, since a nonabelian group that is minimally $k$-generated can have minimally $m$-generated subgroups for $m$ arbitrarily large (e.g., the free group of rank $2$; and every countable group can be embedded in a $2$-generated set). Once you have it for torsionfree groups, it should follow by letting $G$ be a quotient of a free abelian group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick sketch proof - more detail on request.

First suppose that $\max\{ d(H) : H \le G, H\ \mbox{f.g.} \} = n$ is finite. We claim that $r(G) \le 2n$. If not then, either $r_0(G) > n$ or $r_p(G) > n$ for some prime $p$.

In the first case, there is a torsion-free subgroup $H$ with $r(H) > n$, so $H$ contains a set $s_1,\ldots,s_{n+1}$ independent elements. Then, putting $H = \langle s_1,\ldots,s_{n+1} \rangle$. we have $d(H) = n+1$, contradiction. The argument when $r_p(G) > n$ is similar.

Conversely, suppose that $r(G) = n$ is finite. We claim that $\max\{ d(H) : H \le G, H\ \mbox{f.g.} \} \le 2n+1$. If not, then there exists $H \le G$ with $d(H) = 2n+1$.

By the fundamental theorem of abelian groups, we have
$$H \cong {\mathbb Z}^r \oplus \frac{\mathbb Z}{d_1{\mathbb Z}} \oplus \cdots \oplus \frac{\mathbb Z}{d_s{\mathbb Z}}$$
for integers $r,s \ge 0, d_i>1$ with each $d_i|d_{i+1}$.

Then $d(H) =r+s$, so either $r>n$ or $s>n$. If $r>n$ then the generators of the subgroup ${\mathbb Z}^r$ are independent, contradicting $d(G) = n$, and similarly if $s>n$.