# For $H\le G$, abelian $G$, show that $r_0(H)+r_0(G/H)=r_0(G)$, where $r_0(K)$ is the torsionfree rank of $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, quotient-group, infinite-groups

This is **Exercise 4.2.7(i)** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24r_0(H)%2Br_0(G%2FH)%3Dr_0(G)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aabelian%2C%20OR%20content%3Atorsion%2C%20OR%20content%3AGroup&p=10), it is new to MSE.

I've asked two previous questions on based on earlier exercises on a related concept:

- [If $G$ is abelian, show the Prüfer rank $r(G)$ is finite iff $\max\{ d(H)\}$ is finite, for $d(H)$ the min number of generators of f.g. $H\le G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4195267/104041)
- [An abelian group has Prüfer rank at most one iff it is isomorphic to a subgroup of either $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4201018/104041)

### The Details:

On page 98 to 99, *ibid.*, we have

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $G$. Then  $S$ is called *linearly independent*, or simply *independent*, if $0\notin S$ and, given distinct elements $s_1,\dots, s_r$ of $S$ and integers $m_1,\dots, m_r$, the relation $m_1s_1+\dots+m_rs_r=0$ implies $m_is_i=0$ for all $i$.

. . . and . . .

> [T]he *$0$-rank* or *torsion-free rank*
>
> $$r_0(G)$$
>
> is the cardinality of a maximal independent subset of elements of infinite order.

### The Question:

> If $H$ is a subgroup of an abelian group $G$, prove that [. . .]
> $$r_0(H)+r_0(G/H)=r_0(G).$$

### Thoughts:

Since $G$ is abelian, so is $H$, which is then normal in $G$, and so $G/H$ is a group; the quotient of any abelian group by any subgroup is itself abelian. Hence the exercise makes sense.

---

If $K$ is a finite, abelian group, then $r_0(K)=0$, so the result is trivial if $G$ is finite.

---

I'm not sure how to handle when $H$ is finite while $G$ is infinite; of course, I would need to show that $r_0(G/H)=r_0(G)$.

---

If $G$ is finitely generated, then $H$ is not necessarily finitely generated. It might help to consider when $H$ is finitely generated. I'm stuck here though.

---

For some reason, I get the impression that the axiom of choice is required, since the axiom is equivalent to the statement that each vector space has a basis. I mean this in the sense that perhaps there is an analogy between the maximal independent subset of elements of infinite order and the basis of a vector space.

I am not well-versed in the axiom of choice.

---

This seems like a problem I ought to be able to answer myself. But I would like to move on: I've given it a few days and I doubt I could make fruitful progress any time soon.

---

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does it.

Let $\{h_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a linearly independent subset of elements of infinite order of $H$, and given a linearly independent subset $S$ of elements of infinite order of $G/H$, say indexed by $J$, for each $j\in J$ let $g_j$ be an element of $G$ such that $g_jH$ is an element of $S$, so $S=\{g_jH\}_{j\in J}$. Note that because $g_jH$ is of infinite order in $G/H$, then $g_j$ is of infinite order in $G$. Note also that $\langle g_j\mid j\in J\rangle\cap H$ must be trivial: otherwise, there exist $j_1,\ldots,j_k\in J$, and nonzero integers $a_1,\ldots,a_k$, such that $a_1g_{j_1}+\cdots+a_kg_{j_k}\in H$, which means this combination is trivial in $G/H$, which means that $a_tg_{j_t}$ is trivial in $G/H$, which means that $g_{j_t}$ has finite order in $G/H$, a contradiction.

Let us consider $\{h_i\}_{i\in I}\cup\{g_j\}_{j\in J}$. I claim that this is linearly independent in $G$. Indeed, say we have a linear combination of elements of $H$ and $g_j$ equal to $0$;  but because $\langle g_j\mid j\in J\rangle$ intersects $H$ trivially, this combination leads to a linear combination of $h_i$ equal to $0$ and one of the $g_j$ equal to $0$. So these are themselves equal to $0$, and hence are the trivial linear combination.

This shows that $r_0(G)$ is *at least* $r_0(H)+r_0(G/H)$.

Now let $\{g_k\}_{k\in K}$ be a maximal linearly independent set of elements of infinite order in $G$. It is possible that some of the $g_k$ have finite order in $G/H$, so divide $K$ into a disjoint union, $K = K_1\cup K_2$, where for each $k\in K$, we have that $k\in K_1$ if and only if $g_k$ has finite order in $G/H$.

If $k\in K_1$, then there exists $r\gt 0$ such that $rg_k\in H$; but the element is nontrivial, since $g_k$ has infinite order in $G$. Fix such an $r$ and let $h_k=rg_k$. Note that because $\{g_k\}_{k\in K_1}$ is independent, it follows that $\{h_k\}_{k\in K_1}$ is an independent subset of $H$. Thus, $|K_1|\leq r_0(H)$.

We are now going to do a bit of a shuffle: it's possible for the $g_k$ with $k\in K_2$ to *not* be linearly independent in $G/H$ (here's the example I had in mind: take $G=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, $H=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\{0\}$, and $g_1=(1,1)$, $g_2=(0,1)$. Then both elements are of infinite order in $G/H$, but they are not independent).

Let's well-order $K$, since you are okay with the Axiom of Choice. I wonder if the following can be justified without this, but I don't know and this seems straightforward, so here goes.

If $\{g_kH\mid k\in K_2\}$ is linearly independent in $G/H$, we are done. Otherwise, there is a least index $r\in K_2$ such that $\{g_kH\mid k\in K_2,k\leq r\}$ is linearly dependent in $G/H$. Thus there is a nontrivial linear combination $0\neq h_r=\sum_{i\leq r}a_ig_i \in H$, with $a_r\neq 0$. Note that $h_r$ is linearly independent from $\{h_k\mid k\in K_1\}$, because the original family was linearly independent. Thus, if we replace $g_r$ with $h_r$, we obtain a set that remains linearly independent in $G$, and we've moved an index from $K_2$ to $K_1$. The least index in $K$ that witnesses that $\{g_kH\mid k\in K_2\}$ is linearly dependent in $G/H$ is now larger than $r$.

This process allows us to set up a transfinite induction on the well-ordered set $K$ that will replace our original collection with a new collection that is still linearly independent, still contains only elements of infinite order, is still partitioned into $K_1$ and $K_2$, but now $\{g_kH\mid k\in K_2\}$ is linearly independent in $G/H$. Because linear combinations are inherently finite, the limit step is exactly the same as the regular step.

At the end of the transfinite induction, we have a disjoint union $K=K_1\cup K_2$, with $\{h_k\mid k\in K_1\}$ linearly independent in $H$, and $\{g_kH\mid k\in K_2\}$ linearly independent in $G/H$. This shows that $|K_1|\leq r_0(H)$ and $|K_2|\leq r_0(G/H)$, hence $|K|\leq r_0(H)+r_0(G/H)$. Thus, $r_0(G)$ is bounded above by $r_0(H)+r_0(G/H)$, proving the other inequality.

Comment: Thank you, @ArturoMagidin :)

Comment: @Shaun: No problem; there's a few details you may want to verify. Also, on further thinking, it should be possible to just do the 'induction' in one go, without first splitting $K$, just at each step, if the images of the ones you haven't "moved out" plus $g_r$ are linearly independent, keep $g_r$; otherwise, replace $g_r$ with the suitable element of $H$ and move it over to the other set. The limit case is immediate because if the union up to $\gamma$ yields linear dependence, then that shows up in an intermediate step.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $\gamma$.

Comment: @Shaun: A limit ordinal. In doing transfinite induction, one often has to distinguish between the steps proving the case for $\beta+1$ from the case of $\beta$, and proving the case for limit ordinals $\gamma$ from the cases for all $\beta\lt \gamma$. Think about how proving that the $n$th case implies the $(n+1)$st case does not show that a proposition holds for the $\omega$ case. Limit ordinals usually require separate arguments in transfinite induction proofs.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense; thanks again!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: On the other hand, typically one does not need to distinguish successor from limit ordinals if the (purely order-based) strong transfinite induction suffices, in which case we do not even need ordinals because there is a very short proof of the well-ordering theorem that does not need ordinals at all.